# Always load MPart when opening screen

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have created a perspective with multiple MParts. Now when I open the perspective only one MPart will be loaded and shown. How can I force the other MParts (that currently not visible only the tab is visible) to be loaded when loading the other MPart? I need this behavior because otherwise the not visible MParts does not accept some injected values.

Comment: The other parts will be injected when they become visible. Why do you need to do this earlier?

Comment: My perspective contains different Mpart with one parent MPart. When the user selects an object in the parent MPart the other MParts need to update their data.

Comment: That doesn't explain why they need to be created early. They should get the necessary data when they are eventually shown. Anyway there is no way to create the parts before they are shown.

Comment: It actually sounds like you probably need some 'manager' object holding your data which all the parts can inject. MParts should be views on to data managed by something else.

Comment: Ok so there is no way to force this behavior in Eclipse E4. Manager object is then the easiest way to fix this in my setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes for MParts are not creating until they are about to be shown. There is no way to get this done earlier.

Probably you need to create a 'manager' object that holds your data and state which all the parts can access as required. You could create this in your LifeCycle class (if you have one) perhaps in the @PostContextCreate method.